# Adding an object to the list after deleting another object in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have this piece of code, which creates a list:

```
rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for(int i=0;i<nameData.length;i++){
    if(nameData[i]==null) break;
        model.addElement(nameData[i]);
    }
final JList list = new JList();
list.setModel(model);
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
listScroller.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
rightPanel.add(listScroller);
```

When I select the object from that list, I have a button which it makes it possible to delete the selected object:

```
rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
final JButton deleteConfirmButton = new JButton("Kustuta");
deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(false);
rightPanel.add(deleteConfirmButton);
deleteConfirmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        model.removeElementAt(listIndex);
        nameData[listIndex] = null;
        deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

But after deleting the object, when I'm trying to add a new object to the same array that the list is made of, it won't show the changes in the list anymore.

Comment: 'add a new object to the same array that the list is made of' What do you mean by that, exactly?

Comment: Basically that I want to add an object to the array, where the list takes it's objects from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
//Adds the data from the textfield to corresponding string.
String name = nameTextField.getText();
String eMail = eMailTextField.getText();
String dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthTextField.getText();
String address = addressTextField.getText();

//Stores the string data in an array.
nameData[n] = name;
eMailData[n] = eMail;
dateOfBirthData[n] = dateOfBirth;
addressData[n] = address;
```

Why do you have plenty of arrays such as `nameData[]`, `emailData[]` etc ? Don't be better create a class to hold this info instead? For instance:

```
class Data {

    String name;
    String email;
    Date dateOfBirth;
    String address;

    public Data(String name, String email, Date dateOfBirth, String address){ ... }

    // getters and setters here
}
```

Then in your list model you can add `Data` objects like this:

```
String name = nameTextField.getText();
String eMail = eMailTextField.getText();
String dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthTextField.getText();
String address = addressTextField.getText();

DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
model.add(new Data(name, eMail, dateOfBirth, address));
```

Please take a carefully read to **[How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)** tutorial. It's your friend.

Comment: I understand that this could be a more convenient way to store the data, but does this solve the problem of the list not refreshing? The problem occurs when I delete an item from it, before deleting, it works normally when adding and editing the information.

Comment: Basically if you work directly adding/removing elements in the model then your problem will be solved. The `model` is responsible to notify the `view` that data has been changed and this last one should be updated without any problem. @danrodi